# The legal distinction between gambling and insurance [USA]

Tags: united-states, gambling, insurance

[28 US Code §5362(1)(A)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/31/5362) defines a bet or wager to be:

> the staking or risking by any person of something of value upon the
>   outcome of a contest of others, a sporting event, or a game subject to
>   chance, upon an agreement or understanding that the person or another
>   person will receive something of value in the event of a certain
>   outcome

(1)(E) then explicitly states that this does not include, *inter alia*, "any contract for insurance".

My question is this: Ignoring (1)(E) and relying solely on the literal text of (1)(A), would insurance contracts have to be considered bets or wagers?

Answer (score 8):

Gambling creates a risk where none exists. Gambling provides the opportunity for gains or losses.

Insurance mitigates an existing risk of loss. The buyer of insurance has no opportunity for gain. The opportunity is to be made whole.

EDIT: I suppose that I have provided the *practical* difference. The *legal* difference is that the statute distinguishes between the two.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: That's a very idealistic view of insurance.  The seller of insurance certainly has an expected positive gain.  The buyer has an opportunity for gain, although he can't have *expected* positive gain without committing fraud.

Comment: Idealistic, perhaps. Widely accepted, definitely.

Comment: @KennyLJ: how does this not answer the question? The insuree does not receive something of value, they loose something of value, and then have all or a portion of that loss repaid.  Insurance reduces your loss, it does not eliminiate it, because your payments are not repaid.

Comment: @jmoreno Insurance meets the quoted legal definition of gambling.  The question is, why isn't it legally considered gambling?

Comment: @jmoreno The quoted legal definition does not say that the certain outcome cannot be a loss of value.

Comment: @jmoreno So, in your mind, it's not gambling if you pay an up-front "fee" (which you always lose) instead of a "wager" (which you sometimes get back)?

Comment: @jmoreno So in your mind it's not gambling if you're guaranteed to lose money? Interesting, the quotation doesn't say that...

Comment: @user253751: not a contest, not a sporting event, not a game of chance.  Not gambling.  The specific exclusion is there so that there is no confusion about athletes and other situations where someone might think it possibly applies.

Comment: @jmoreno so you believe Alexanne's answer is more correct than your own?

Comment: @user253751: it’s not my answer.  And no.  Alexanne’s answer is legally correct, but doesn’t address the spirit of the law.  This answer does.  Insurance isn’t viewed as gambling because nobody “wins”.  You risk for a reward, gambling.  Insurance cost and recovery of damage, and is no more gambling than paying more for a builder that promises that if it breaks within a year,  it’ll be fixed for free.  While they might seem similar, they are actually polar opposites.

Comment: @jmoreno So the law is different from what is actually written in the law?

Comment: @user253751: this question isn’t about the actual law, because the actual statue explicitly says that insurance isn’t covered (per the question).

Answer (score 4):

I would say no.

The language requires a bet or wager to be based upon one of:

1. a contest
2. a sporting event
3. a game

Since insurance involves none of those things, I would say the answer is, "no."

*I assume when you write "insurance" you mean the typical types of insurance like property, casualty, life, fire, etc.*

Comment: I agree with this. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: What about event insurance (a.k.a. cancellation insurance)?  Especially if bought for a sporting event?  (Not sure what this would prove, other than that it's important to read statutes in their entirety?)

Comment: @feetwet: Agreed. My comment in italics was intended to exclude "specialty" type insurances like "raffle ticket insurance" or "hole-in-one" insurances that are often purchased and sold for promotional events. I'm sure the insurance companies have various carveouts in their respective codes for that (e.g., (1)(E)). But I felt the intent of the question was aimed at insurance in the main.

Comment: Is there a legal definition of what "a game subject to chance" is? (It would seem to me that a contract with payouts contingent on whether the White House burns down is no less "a game subject to chance" than a contract based on whether the New York Yankees win the next World Series.)

Comment: @KennyLJ: Not sure if there is a legal definition of game. But there is a dictionary definition: "a form of play or sport, especially a competitive one played according to rules and decided by skill, strength, or luck." There is also a "game theory" definition: "...the outcome is determined by the behaviors of at least two players according to a set of rules." The scenario you present is "subject to chance" but not "a game" under those ordinary definitions. If you have a definition of a game that would include a naturally disaster as one, please share it. I would be curious.

Comment: @KennyLJ: There is a legal term called "[Force Majeure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_majeure)" or ("act of God") encompassing events that typically trigger an insurance payout. This is legally distinguishable from a "game."

Answer (score 3):

*In general* insurance is not gambling (according to that law).  However consider a golf club which has a tradition that if you hit a hole in one, you buy everyone in the club a bottle of champagne.  In that case, you might take out insurance against those costs, and *that* depends on "a sporting contest" (or possibly "a game").  As such, without the exception you quote, this insurance policy would be illegal gambling.

Comment: When the lottery started in the UK 20 years ago, you were offered insurance for the risk that your ten employees started a syndicate, won the lottery, and all quit their jobs at the same time. You don't hear of that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: insurance isn’t gambling, but has sufficient similarities that it is better to be explicit.

Possibly under some circumstances.  Consider insurance for a race car, if the vehicle wins it probably won’t be totaled, conversely if it is totaled, it probably won’t win.  Lesser damage also decreases the chance of winning to some extent.  Could it be considered gambling to insure the vehicle when the payout will depend upon a skill utilized in a sport?

The spirit or intention of the law is clear, but courts rarely rule on what the law meant, but rather on what it actually says.  So, an explicit statement is added saying that regardless of any other factor, insurance isn’t to be considered gambling.

As for the difference between the two and why insurance is allowed while gambling isn’t.  It’s for the same reason that damages from lawsuits aren’t taxable —- it’s not considered a gain, but instead countering a loss.  Insurance isn’t a contest, where you risk your assets in order to get a reward. The insurer doesn’t get a reward if the event happens, and the insuree’s “gain” isn’t considered a gain, but rather a restoration to normal (or wholeness). Thus no one gains and there is no risk/reward taking place.

The insurance companies loss might be considered gambling, but they are expected to take that into account so that it is an expected expense and not a gamble.  Pure applied statistics with a margin sufficient to prevent their expenses from out running revenue.  States have laws requiring liquidity coverage ratio, in order to make sure that gamble isn’t too much for them to afford.